# Laravel routing: is there a syntax to pass a fixed parameter to the handler function?

Tags: laravel, syntax, routes

I am using Laravel 8 and currently I have the following route:

```
Route::match(['get'], '/{action}', '\App\Http\MyController@handleRequest');
```

In the MyController class I have a handlerRequest function which takes two parameters

```
public function handleRequest(Request $request, string $action) 
{
    // Generic request handling code for every action, both GET and POST
    // This code is fairly long and I don't want it to be duplicated
}
```

This all works well until I want to add another route for a specific request:

```
Route::match(['post'], '/message-sent', '\App\Http\MyController@handleRequest');
```

In this case only the POST method is allowed on the specific action `message-sent`, however it does not work using the above configuration as Laravel does not pass "message-sent" as $action to the handleRequest function.

The error message is

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\MyController::handleRequest(), 1 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php on line 48 and exactly 2 expected
```

What I want is the action "message-sent" is passed into the generic handler function as parameter but at the same time achieving the "special post-only setting" for this specific route.

I tried

```
Route::match(['post'], '/{message-sent}', '\App\Http\MyController@handleRequest');
```

as well without success.

Comment: Try changing the order of the routes

Comment: Tried but the error message still shows up, "number of arguments expected to be 2 but only 1 passed"

Answer (score 2):

After searching through the Laravel source code, I think I found the solution

```
Route::match(['post'], '/message-sent', '\App\Http\MyController@handleRequest')->defaults('action', 'message-sent');
```

would achieve the effect of sending a fixed parameter $action="message-sent" to the handler function.